How do I fade animate the material opacity value of a node?
I've tried different approaches and none seem to work.
I have a GLTF model, I have acquired a node that has a mesh, the node has a material, but I don't know how to apply an animation to the opacity value of that material?
This is a specific problem tied GLTFs with materials, and OBJs with .mtl applied, when applying the animation to an OBJ with a material applied from within the scene there is no problem, however this becomes messy with many meshes and materials.
Any ideas?
Attempt 1
 if (node.isMesh) {
                node.material.transparent = node.material.opacity < 1.0;
                node.material.needsUpdate = true;

                // error: node.setAttribute is not a function from here
                
                node.setAttribute('animation', {
                  property: "material.opacity",
                  from: 0,
                  to: 1,
                  dur: 2000,
                  easing: "easeInQuad",
                  loop: false,
                });
              }
            });

Attempt 2
if (node.isMesh) {
                node.material.transparent = node.material.opacity < 1.0;
                node.material.needsUpdate = true;

                // error: node.appendChild is not a function from here

                const animation = document.createElement("a-animation");
                animation.setAttribute("attribute", "material.opacity");
                animation.setAttribute("from", "0");
                animation.setAttribute("to", "1");
                animation.setAttribute("dur", "2000");
                animation.setAttribute("easing", "easeInQuad");
                animation.setAttribute("loop", "false");

                node.appendChild(animation);
              }
            });


I believe this might be what you're looking for

The model nodes are THREE.JS objects, not HTML elements.
So they don't have their own attributes (hence error: node.setAttribute is not a function from here)
To change the "node" opacity, you should use the three API:
const opacity = 0.75;
const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
mesh.traverse(function (node) {
  if (!node.isMesh) return;
  node.material.opacity = opacity;
  node.material.transparent = opacity < 1.0;
  node.material.needsUpdate = true;
});

Ok, but you want it animated. So wrap the above code in an aframe component, expose the opacity with the components schema and target your own component with the animation component:


<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('my-component', {
      schema: { opacity: { default: 1.0 } },
      update: function () {
        var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
        var data = this.data;
        if (!mesh) return;
        mesh.traverse(function (node) {
            if (!node.isMesh) return;
            node.material.opacity = data.opacity;
            node.material.transparent = data.opacity < 1.0;
            node.material.needsUpdate = true;
        });
      }
  });
</script>
<a-scene>
   <a-box position="0 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" 
   my-opacity="opacity: 0.50"
   animation='property: my-component.opacity;from: 1; to: 0; dur: 500;loop: true; dir: alternate;'></a-box>
</a-scene>



This might also be helpful.

Thank you! I could not find this in the a-frame documentation. I need to look at THREE.JS a little closer.
